# public List<(Of <(<'T>)>)>..::..Enumerator?

Tags: c#, generics, syntax, methods, signature

I'm looking at the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765.aspx) about List.GetEnumerator.

They say the C# method signature is:

```
public List<(Of <(<'T>)>)>..::..Enumerator GetEnumerator()
```

I was expecting this much simpler signature:

```
public List<T>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
```

What does their signature mean, with all the punctuation and the "Of" keyword?

**Edit**: Well, I guess if no one has seen that syntax, then the MSDN docs are just a bit buggy, and that's all.

Comment: Have a link to the offending documentation?

Comment: @Justin, yeah, forgot to include the link, sorry.

Comment: Yea, that does look weird. WTH is that??

Comment: +1 Good question.  When I asked visual studio to figure out the signature (from the metadata), it gave the signature you expected.  Then again, I don't have .Net 4.0.

Comment: Looks like a bug as its evident on all the language tabs.

Comment: It appears to be an error in the docs.  `Of` is a VB.NET keyword for generics.  For example, in VB, `List<T>` would be `List(Of T)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN uses some code generation to supply that signature for all of the different languages, and this looks like a bug in that code which forgets to take the actual language into account and just outputs all of the syntax - everythign in there can be matched to the expected syntax for such a return type in *some* language (although, admittedly, I'm not entirely sure where the apostrophe is from).

The same problem can be seen on other pages, such as the very similar [HashSet.GetEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341120.aspx), but not on others, like [Queryable.AsQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003.aspx), so it seems likely that they don't generate everything at once, and the bug was introduced/removed between the generation of those two pages. (Since we don't know how new each of those are, we can't guess if it's already been fixed.)

I don't know if they have automatic re-generation running every now and then, but if they do, it will probably fix itself soon. If not, you could leave a comment about it in the Community Content section.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a mistake in MSDN.  Take a look at how Queue is defined:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=VS.90).aspx